# Idempiere: 'External POS Integration' option not showing up in Menu

Tags: activemq-classic, idempiere, unicenta

I am trying to setup Unicenta POS on my Windows 10 64 bit machine.

My configuration:

1. Idempiere server v5.1 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/)
2. ActiveMQ v5.15.2
   (http://127.0.0.1:8161/)
3. POS Integration plugin ([Available
   here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/red1/files/UnicentaPOS/POSIntegration2_4.1.0.201709130853.jar/download))

I followed instructions given [Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/red1/files/UnicentaPOS/). ActiveMQ is running fine, Unicenta can also send request to ActiveMQ, I can see that in Queues. Idempiere server is also running fine.

[image]

I installed POS integration plugin through Felix Web Console. It shows up in the list and It is active. But, that plugin doesn't show up in Idempiere Menu option. Either that plugin has some problems or I am missing something.

[image]

I also performed Role Access Update on GardenWorld Client Admin but that didn't change anything. Menu option is still missing.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was that `2Pack` did not `Pack in` into the Database. I had install `2Pack` manually and `Pack In` in my SystemAdmin. After that I logged out and logged in with SuperUser credentials and with GardenAdmin role. And then menu item appeared!

2Pack zip file location - [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/red1/files/UnicentaPOS/2Pack_1.0.0.zip/download)

How to Pack In:

[image]